# Linux/windows time to sleep

Tags: c++, python, linux, windows, bash

Is it possible to check (in bash/python/C++ ) how much time left to go to sleep in system (Linux/Windows) - i need it to create double program working on linux and windows preventing one from go to sleep mode when working on another one (over TCP).

No i cannot just enlarge system time to go to sleep - because if i go away from desk computers MUST go to sleep (or rather to block mode - or whatever it is called - they just need to be blocked by password - security issues).

Comment: do you mean before it goes in to lock mode? that is, you have to reenter your password to unlock the computer. or do you mean before the computer goes into sleep mode? that is, when the power is (more or less) turned off for the computer and you have to push a button to start it up.

Comment: yes you are right - to lock mode - to reenter password to unlock the computer.

Comment: On Windows, see `SystemParametersInfo()` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx.  But I think it only allows you to get/set the limits, so it might not be an answer.  On Linux it will be GUI specific, you need to specify which GUI (Gnome, KDE, etc), but again I doubt you can.

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 10.04, and windows 7. Hmmm...  if it can't be done that way, maybe I will just inform application over TCP each 30 seconds that it should prevent computer from sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows :

[SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will tell the system not to go into sleep mode, it can also reset the idle timer.

If you know the time limit, you could use [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a simple subtraction to know how much time you have left before the system goes to sleep.

Comment: Thanks - this will help from the windows site - but still don't know how to do it on linux.